# BaseX Replace Command

Tags: xml, basex

I was trying baseX replace query, replace goes all fine but all the `<` an d`>` characters in my XML are getting stored as `&lt;` and `&gt;` in the DB. Can somebody help how to prevent this.? Now I have to read the DB and then replace these `&lt;` and `&gt;` with the respective characters.

Comment: What command exactly are you executing and what is your input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using XQuery to archive it you should definitely check the serialization options on http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Serialization

I hope it helped by the resolution of your problems